# Calling all ISomething instances in Autofac

Tags: autofac

I have an interface ISomething with a method Start.
I want to get all implementations of this interface (in multiple assemblies, the main one and all referenced ones) and call the Start method on application start.
How can I do this with Autofac 2.4.4.705?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can resolve

```
 IEnumerable<ISomething>
```

and call Start for each of them

Forgot to mention, that you should first register all implementations of ISomething.

```
Assembly[] assemblies = ...;
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies).AssignableTo<ISomething>().As<ISomething>();
var container = builder.Build();
```

Where "assemblies" is an array of assemblies you want to register from.

Comment: Any idea why I don't see the RegisterAssemblyTypes method? All I see are Build, Update, RegisterCallback.

Comment: Also is there any way to get the list of assemblies without hardcoding them?

Comment: Nevermind about not seeing the RegisterAssemblyTypes method i figured out the problem. The extension methods don't become available unless I import Autofac at the top of the class rather than using it inline.

Comment: Exactly - those are extension methods in different namespace

Comment: As for hardcoding the assemblies - you can pass them as parameter. You can search for them in some directory/ies.