# Calling all ISomething instances in Ninject

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

I have an interface ISomething with a method Start. I want to get all implementations of this interface (in multiple assemblies, the main one and all referenced ones) and call the Start method on application start. How can I do this with Ninject 2.2.0.0 .NET 4.0?

Autofac answer was here
[Calling all ISomething instances in Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074719/calling-all-isomething-instances-in-autofac)

Answer (score 10):

You may try [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/Overview)  :

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind(c =>
            c.FromThisAssembly()
                .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IFoo>()
                .BindAllInterfaces());

// and later:

kernel.GetAll<IFoo>().ToList().ForEach(foo => foo.DoSmth());
```

Needed classes are below:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoSmth();
}

public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public void DoSmth()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Foo1");
    }
}

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public void DoSmth()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Foo2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to find all classes that implement the interface(s): http://cocaine.co.nz/Home/High-On-Ninject-BLLModule

What do you mean by the "main one"? - call the Start() method on which one?